# Add a larger number of block users via one Twitter Api request

Tags: twitter, blocking

I just learn about Twitter for couple of days. I 'm facing a problems in building an app that add a large number of users to block list via Twitter Api (POST blocks/list ). But this Api is only work with one user per request, using it will lead to 'API RATE LIMIT'. That I want here is a method that can add a lot of users to the block list via one request Can anyone help me overcome this problem ? Thank and best regards. Like this site http://blocktogether.org/

Answer (score 0):

You're getting two things confused.

There is `GET blocks/list` which allows you to receive a list of a blocked users.

On the other hand `POST blocks/create` allows you to block users from your twitter account. I believe that's the one you're wanting.

Either way they're both rate limited and you'll need to send multiple requests to the twitter API in order to reach whatever number you're looking into adding. As of now, until twitter decides to change it, it's only 1 user at a time.